# Populating PHP page with MySQL info from a variable in the URL

Tags: php, mysql, url, get, mysqli

I'm trying to create unique urls for user's of a site I'm designing. Basically I want the url to look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/page.php?user_id=3
```

Or whatever user_id they are assigned. Basically I want user to be able to go to that url and it generates the page with the info (first name, last name, etc.) of the user from the row in the MySQL table with that user id number. I know that creating the URL would be done by $_GET but this is sort of backwards from that. I want them to be able to go to the URL and the pages gets the variables from the URL.

Sorry if this is basic, I'm having trouble searching for an answer because it always gives me the answer on how to submit a form TO the URL not FROM the URL. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
```

you could use this to get the variable.And then search the database for the matching id and get get all the details.
Since you want to contain all the details in you form.You could keep adding the other elements like this.

```
http://www.example.com/page.php?user_id=3&first_name=Max&last_name=Payne
```

Using $_GET[which element you want the value of]

Answer (score 3):

Accessing the get variables on the page is really simple!.In your case as you want to access the user id,you can get from $_GET['user_id'] and fire the respective query to fetch the user details to populate the page.For more reference you could check here 
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Ah that answers my first question, that'll get me started. That was WAY easier than I thought, I didn't realize you just do it like that. Haha, thanks!